# How to remove `InteractiveViewer` initial extra space?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a 'spot the differences' game. I would like the user to zoom in on the image because the differences can be a little small. When the image is smaller than the reserved space, I would like to allow only center zoom and movement in the axis that is already occupying the full axis. When the image is fully zoomed, then allow the user to move around on all axes until they reach the image borders.

I have the following code (simplified):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final transformationController = TransformationController();

  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.orange),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                transformationController: transformationController,
                child: Center(
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          end: Alignment.centerRight,
                          colors: <Color>[Colors.black, Colors.orange],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(color: Colors.black12, height: 4, thickness: 4),
            Expanded(
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                transformationController: transformationController,
                child: Center(
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          end: Alignment.centerRight,
                          colors: <Color>[Colors.black, Colors.orange],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, this does not work as expected; there is extra space. I should only be allowed to move vertically or horizontally until the image reaches something like 'BoxFit.cover.'

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?